# what is the lightest docker image to be used for automation test?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to create a docker image to run the UI automation test in headless mode.

it should contain:
NodeJs, JDK, chrome browser.

I have created the one below, which is 1.6 GB, is there a better way to make it lighter and optimized

```
FROM node:slim

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

WORKDIR /project
#=============================
# Install Dependenices 
#=============================
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]   

RUN apt update && apt install -y wget bzip2 openjdk-11-jre xvfb libnotify-dev

#==============================
# install chrome
#==============================
RUN wget  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/${CHROME_PACKAGE} && \
    dpkg-deb -x ${CHROME_PACKAGE} / && \
    apt-get install -f -y

#=========================
# Copying Scripts to root
#=========================
COPY . /project
RUN chmod a+x ./execute_test.sh

#=======================
# framework entry point
#=======================
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your build will fail if not use `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]`? Otherwise eliminate this line can save you a layer. You can combine the 2 RUN into one which save you a few more. Then try [--squash](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) flag when building your image. Note your docker daemon needs to have [experiment enabled](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#description) to use this flag. You should get a smaller image using these steps.